# how to limit the display width in polars so that wide dataframes are printed in a legible way?

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Consider the following example

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 50)

pl.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(0,20, size = (10, 42)),
             columns = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFG')).to_pandas()
```

[image]

You can see how nicely the columns are formatted, breaking a line after column k so that the full dataframe is printed in chunks in the console. This was controlled by the pandas `width` argument above. I was not able to reproduce this behavior using `polars` and all the `format options`.

I have tried tweaking all possible settings:

```
pl.Config.set_tbl_cols(10)
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(10)
pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(70)
pl.Config.set_tbl_rows(2)
pl.Config.set_tbl_formatting('NOTHING')
pl.Config.set_tbl_column_data_type_inline(True)  
pl.Config.set_tbl_dataframe_shape_below(True)
```

See below:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: It looks like `display.expand_frame_repr` is the important option which tells pandas to *"wrap-around across multiple pages if its width exceeds display.width"* - I don't think polars has such functionality yet.

Comment: that would be a really useful feature. Most of us work with dataframe containing dozens of dataframe. the ability to see all columns at once is really important

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? If not, how are you handling it? Just asked something similar at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76639935/polars-x-pandas-dataframe-printed-at-ipython-console-in-spyder-ide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can display all frame columns like so...

```
with pl.Config() as cfg:
    cfg.set_tbl_cols(-1)
    print(df)
```

...which will give you a good result on the given frame *if* you have sufficient terminal/console/output width available. If this isn't enough, I recommend making a [feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_request.yml) for this on the polars GitHub repository

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

```
with pl.Config(fmt_str_lengths=1000):
    print(df)
```

or:

```
with pl.Config(tbl_width_chars=1000):
    print(df)
```

Other options for formatting are here:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html

You can also just set the config to stay that way instead of using a `with` context:

`pl.Config(tbl_width_chars=1000)`